# Read excel file from folder in ReactJS project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm-package

I am trying to store data in excel file in separate folder in ReactJS application. To work on excel file, I have installed npm xlxs module. Can someone tell how to read file from workspace. As I have seen, XLXS module fetches files from server. To fetch browser side files, I am trying to using fetch(). Now I want to process fetched data using XLXS provided functions. Can someone explain how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

```
const blob = new Blob([data], { type: "application/xlxs" });
const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = objectUrl;
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```